# can cglib(java) deep copy a bean that has a list property

Tags: java, deep-copy, cglib

here is the code

```
public class Root {
 private Long id;
 private List<Child> list;
 //getter and setter
}
public class Child {
 private Long id;
 //getter and setter
}

public static void main(String args) {
    Child child = new Child();
    child.setId(1L);
    List<Child> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(child);
    Root root = new Root();
    Root copyRoot = new Root();
    root.setId(2L);
    root.setList(list);

    BeanCopier copier1 = BeanCopier.create(Root.class, Root.class, false);
    copier1.copy(root, copyRoot, null);
    //can beancopier in cglib deep copy this root to copyRoot?
    //because i found when i used beancopier the two instances still point the same list instance
}
```

can beancopier in cglib deep copy this root to copyRoot?
because i found when i used beancopier the two instances still point the same list instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that cglib can improve copying using code generation is to create a class that subclasses the supplied class. cglib would need to do this for every nested type without being able to know what instance of a subclass is assigned to each field, therefore, this cannot work.

Generally, I would recommend you to not rely on code generation for this task either; this only really offered a performance benefit in days when the JVM was still young. Modern VMs perform equally well using reflection, for example Apache's bean utities.

Creating an automated deep copy might however not be a good idea in the first place but you might look into [appropriate utilities](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html#clone%28T%29).